# CKEditor jQuery Value is Empty

Tags: ckeditor

CKEditor jquery value ?

var val = jQuery('.ckeditor').val(); 
or
var val = jQuery('textarea[name="content"]').val();

Problem : Value is empty;
CKEditor version 4.x;

help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have instantiated CKEDITOR as it was recommended by tutorials, for example:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo("editorContainer", config, "");
```

then you may get the content by the following call:

```
editor.getData();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this time it was a problem
Console error => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getEditor' of undefined ckeditor.js:285